# Textbox databinding to 2 properties

Tags: vb.net

I have a form that saves to an order data table. A few of the fields in the form are linked to a table that contains customer names and address details. The shippername field in my order data table is a combobox - you select the name and the corresponding address information for that name is displayed in textboxes that belong to the address, city and phone number fields for my order datatable. For that, I am using the databinding property of the combobox control for that field, and using the Text property for the textboxes (binding to the source table, which I call shipperdata.) When I run the form, it displays the information I want.

The problem: when I save the form, the names of the shippers are saved fine. However, the other fields related to the shipper name are not. I realized that the binding property would not let me bind the contents of the textbox to my order datatable.

I went into the designer and thought I'd try an experiment, thinking that if the combobox can bind to a source and bind the text to the order datatable, I should be able to do that with a textbox. Right? Apparently not so much. Here's what I tried:

```
'Shipper1address1TextBox
        '
        Me.Shipper1address1TextBox.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", Me.ShippersBindingSource, "SHIPPERADDRESS1", True))
        Me.Shipper1address1TextBox.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", Me.OrdersBindingSource, "shipper1address1", True))
        Me.Shipper1address1TextBox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(188, 429)
        Me.Shipper1address1TextBox.Name = "Shipper1address1TextBox"
        Me.Shipper1address1TextBox.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(200, 20)
        Me.Shipper1address1TextBox.TabIndex = 32
```

I got an error saying that I couldn't bind 2 properties.

The funny part: the form is actually 'details' so I decided to drag a datagridview next to what I already had set up to see how it looked. In detail view, you'd think the data was being saved correctly to the orders data table. But, when I looked at the table in gridview, the values for the address and phone, etc were not written there. Then i reminded myself that it's only bound to the shipper data table.

My question: how can I save the corresponding address and phone information to the order table while still binding to the source so it displays? If I make the binding property to the orders data table, that's great...except now it doesn't display address information. Is there a method to accomplish this with a textbox? I'm also guessing at this point that messing with the designer is probably not a great idea. Maybe an alternative? It just seems odd that the value contained in a textbox from a data table isn't saved.

Thanks for having a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can only add one databinding to each text box.
You are adding two in your code.......

Me.Shipper1address1TextBox.DataBindings.Add

ArronG.